# How to know if the mouse clicked once on a window's title bar?

Tags: onclick, mouseevent, titlebar, setfocus

I would like to write a Gnome extension that detects a single click on a window's title bar so that I may raise the window, a bit like if the following dconf key existed: `org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences.action-single-click-titlebar="raise"`. I'm essentially trying to bring back the raise on single click on tile bar setting that was useful with sloppy mode focus. Since writing my last Gnome extensions things have changed quite a bit and I am not familiar with gjs. I have not found found any documentation that could help me, could someone please point me in the correct direction?

Thank you!

Gabriel